# How to refer to different (incl. not yet exisiting) sheets in closed workbook

Tags: excel, dashboard, vba

I'm trying to make an efficiency platform for production.

I have the source of the worked hours in the factory.

Worked hours
[image]

- In this we have the hours worked on every workcenter.
- documented every day
- Every week a new sheet is added.

Now I want to refer in another workbook to this data.

Dashboard
[image]

I have used this function to search for the workhours of the given date.

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'[werkuren per afdeling.xls]ww"&$B2&"'!"&A2&"20");"")
```

But this only works when the source workbook is opened. 
Does anyone have a solution **without VBA** please?

Comment: just add the full path in front of the excel sheet. Also, i would strongly recommend not to make use of INDIRECT here, as that's a volatile function... It will kill the performance on the sheet.

Comment: Other problem you have with INDIRECT is that you will have to have the referenced workbook open if you want the function to work.. otherwise you will just get a `REF#` error. This will give you a bit more info: http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html